# Python remove padding characters from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that removes the padding character from a string.

Basically I have two python scripts,

1. one will insert the padding and
2. the other script should remove it.

I already  ave a function that inserts the padding as seen bellow:

```
def padding():
    message = input('Enter your message: ')
    padding = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    extra = len(message) % 16
    if extra > 0:
        paddedMessage = Message + (padding * (16 - extra))
```

I guess what I am asking is what is the best way to remove the padding from the message? Bearing in mind that the padding will always go to a multiple of 16 and will always be a random letter.

Some examples of possible output of the `paddedMessage` could be:

```
helloDDDDDDDDDDD
this is my secret messageqqqqqqq
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `"helloDDDDDDDDDDD".rstrip('D')` but what if padding is the same as the last letter of your message?

Comment: ex: `this is my secret messageeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee`

Comment: I think you have to take a step back and ask "What's the correct way to pad a string?".

Comment: Yeah... that could also be a problem, I didn't think of that, and I don't think I can explicitly state paddedMessage.rstrip('D') because the next time I run the script the paddedMessage could be hellobbbbbbbbbbb

Comment: `paddedMessage.rstrip(paddedMessage[-1])` then...

Comment: If the padding letter is the same as the last letter in your message or there hasn't been any padding added then I think you can't do this without knowing something about the semantics of the message or the length of the padding

Comment: you could pick a padding letter outside the existing letters of the message, but if there's no padding at all because your message size is a multiple of 16 you're back to square one.

Comment: You have to know something about the padding, most paddings schemes out there follow an RFC...

Comment: what's the point of this? adding some salt? in that case, add a dot or any other char before the padding chars (that can't be in the message) so you can split.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre that did work in removing the padded characters but I should probably now do some testing of it, see what works and what doesn't. eg. this is my secret messageeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Since you literally just did the padding yourself, I'm sure you can share some info on the padding (like the length) to your remove_padding function!

Comment: @Chris_Rands knowing the length kills the fun :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre depends on what the OP wants to use the padding for

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre basically have to write an encryption and decryption program, the messaged has to be padded to be a multiple of 16 then converted into bytes so the additional python cryptography module can use it to then encrypt it.

Comment: @MacGenius you don't have to re-invent the wheel - you can pick one of the standard paddings used

Comment: so pad the message with a non-ASCII char, or spaces.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The task becomes likely impossible without the length, consider `'pureeeeeeeeeeeee'`, where both `'pure'` or `'puree'` are valid words

Comment: yeah I know, my first comment was exactly that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that is an idea.

Comment: Upon looking at my notes I should either use a random fixed character to pad (like i've done above), or use the length (of the string i'm guessing) as the character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As all comments state, it's impossible to get back your original string using the same characters your string contains.

Even if you pick an ascii letter that your string *doesn't* contain, how can you be sure that this letter isn't part of the message, which is the exact size so padding isn't needed?

My proposal would be to pad with a random *non ascii* character.

Then unpadding just checks if the last character is non ascii, and `rstrip`s it, else leave untouched.

```
import string,random

def padding(message):
    padding = chr(random.randint(1,31))
    extra = len(message) % 16
    if extra > 0:
        message += padding * (16 - extra)
    return message

def unpadding(message):
    last_char = message[-1]
    if ord(last_char) < 32:
        return message.rstrip(last_char)
    else:
        return message

p = padding("hello guys")
print(unpadding(p))
```

Comment: Thank @Jean-François Fabre and everybody in the comments. I think this is a good way of doing it while also taking into consideration other factors eg. the random letter is also the last letter of the message causing problems with stripping.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want your padded string to be printed and only use ASCII characters, then you should modify your padding scheme to be uniquely decodable.

There are several of these schemes in other fields, for example cryptography where you have to complete a message to fit the exact block size of the underlying algorithm.

But why this choice of padding?

- Does it have to be random?
- Does it have to be a letter?

If not, take a look for example at PKCS#7.
There, you can add whole bytes to pad your message, but the value of the padding byte changes. If you're adding one byte, it is 1; if you're adding two bytes, it is 2, and so on.
This can be ambiguous it the last block is already complete and does not need any padding. In this case, a whole block of padding is added, with bytes equal to B, where B is the block size. You can see this is exactly the same logic: if you read the last byte (character) of your message, then it tells you how many bytes you have to remove.

If you do have to use letters, and because your padding will be at most 16, then you can use letters from "A" to "P" for example.

Here is an example:

```
def nToChar(n):
if n < 0 or n > 16:
    return ""
else:
    return chr(n + ord("A") - 1)

def charToN(char):
    if char <= "A" or char >= "P":
        return 0
    else:
        return ord(char) - ord("A") + 1

def padding(message):
    lastBlockSize = len(message) % 16 
    padLength = 16 - lastBlockSize  
    pad = nToChar(padLength) * padLength
    return message + pad

def unpadding(message):
    padChar = message[-1]
    nToRemove = charToN(padChar)
    nToReturn = len(message) - nToRemove
    return message[0:nToReturn]
```